# What if the cosmological principle does not hold at larger scales?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, causality, cosmological-inflation

Quite naturally, the observable Universe is the only bit of the Universe we can extract information from, as light from farther away has not reached us yet, and there are zones from which we'll never even be able to extract information, as they are causally disconnected from us due to their high speed. Therefore, how do we know the cosmological principle holds at larger scales if we can't observe them? It just seems to me a quite bold assumption to make that the entire Universe is homogeneous and isotropic. Perhaps it presents irregularities which we'll never know of, and which would be necessary for us to not mess up with our cosmological models. Frankly, I don't quite see the point of building cosmological models if we only know what seems to be a small portion of the Universe, **just like it makes no sense to try to see the picture of a jigsaw puzzle just by examining one random piece of it**.

Comment: I find it quite useful to have a map of my town even though it's not a lot like most of the rest of the surface of the Earth.

Comment: What's the point of the bold-faced part of the question? Is it supposed to be some sort of "gotcha!" remark?

Comment: "I don't quite see the point of building cosmological models if we only know what seems to be a small portion of the Universe" - what do you have in mind that we could be doing instead of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter 27 of the book [Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_(book)) provides a good introduction to idealized cosmologies following the cosmological principle of homogeneity and isotropy.  It is eventually followed by chapter 30 which deals with anisotropic and inhomogeneous models of the universe.

There are several models that are consistent with General Relativity, but which break isotropy or homogeneity.

An example that is anisotropic is Misner's [Mixmaster universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixmaster_universe).

More recent analysis can be found online, an example is a paper called [Inhomogeneous Anisotropic Cosmology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03520).

It is emphasized in Gravitation that nonhomogeneous cosmologies must make some explicit assumption about dependence on spacetime coordinates. One of tools highlighted that is still consistent with General Relativity are [Gowdy spacetimes](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Gowdy_Spacetimes), which assume specific underlying typologies in the metric.

In short, our clinging to the cosmological principle of isotropy and homogeneity is still largely supported by large scale observations, but General Relativity itself would be able to accommodate several types of universes that break the principle.  Any true observation of a break would herald a significant change in cosmology, it is likely that if we discover something of that significance it will come with further analysis of gravitational waves.